# Xamarin - Gradient background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to programmatically set a background gradient like this in Xamarin iOS:

```
CGColor[] colors = new CGColor[] { new UIColor(red: 0.05f, green:0.44f, blue:0.73f, alpha:1.0f).CGColor,
                new UIColor(red: 45/255, green: 128 / 255, blue: 153 / 255, alpha: 0.01f ).CGColor};
            CAGradientLayer gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
            gradientLayer.Frame = this.View.Bounds;
            gradientLayer.Colors = colors;
            this.View.Layer.AddSublayer(gradientLayer);
```

And it works, but I have form elements on the screen (labels, buttons, etc) and this is causing all of them to appear faded, as if the layer appears directly *on top* of the elements. I think this is what the code is doing - it's rendering the entire page, and then adding the layer with opacity on top of the screen (I want it behind it instead).

What I'd like, instead, is to have the background set as gradient, but any elements I add will not be faded and try to match the background colors.

I tried adding a view on top of the standard view, and setting the alpha to 1, background to white, but that didn't seem to help (suggesting my theory that programmatically it's adding a layer on top of everything after it's rendered).

What am I doing wrong?
 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gradient layer that is assign to the root `View` of the `ViewController` is being displayed "behind" all the other Views.

By default, views (UILabel, UIButton, etc) do not have a background color set and thus will *blend* with that background layer, if that is not the effect that you are looking for assign a background to them:

[image]

```
var button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
button.Frame = new CGRect(40, 300, 120, 40);
button.SetTitle("No Background", UIControlState.Normal);
button.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
View.AddSubview(button);

var button2 = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
button2.Frame = new CGRect(180, 300, 100, 40);
button2.SetTitle("Background", UIControlState.Normal);
button2.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
button2.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
View.AddSubview(button2);
```

Comment: hmm, so this doesn't seem to be the case for me; the white in your example is faded out and matches the background color. I even set a view's background to be red, but the red is blending with the gradient. Also for my labels, I just want the label color to be bright white, and not fade. I don't want a background color on my labels. Any thoughts? TY!

Comment: @NullHypothesis Is `this` in `this.View.Layer.AddSublayer` in your example the view controller?

Comment: You got me thinking, and did some more research regarding layering. It seems that using the view's .SendSubviewtoBack() on my layered view will then cause the background to appear first and it worked this way.

Answer (score 4):

I know I am late for the show but for future reference, I use:

```
this.View.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
```

The `0` represents index.